# Jquery- Bootstrap modal slow loading in mobile device

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, performance, cordova, mobile

I have an issue with the loading of ***bootstrap modal in my mobile.***
I have a bootstrap modal with about 150 rows, each row containing and image, a dropdown and a toggle button. I want to open the modal after clicking a textbox. The issue is that the modal is loading only after 3 to 5 seconds after clicking the textbox.

I have used both the methods of loading the bootstrap modal like the "data-toggle and data-target. Also tried to call the modal by giving it and id and calling it through jquery. In both cases the modal loads slow.
The issue is not there in the computer browser but only in the mobile application.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnsLH.jpg)

Each row will be like in the above image.

Please recommend some ssolution to avoid the slowness for loading the bootstrap modal in mobile

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add some code or a problem `snippet/fiddle` replicating the issue?

Comment: are you appending the modal body dynamically??

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments..That was the issue with an inside looping that caused the delay.. now its coming up smooth.